# Reason for not sending the variable

Tags: php, html, css

When I write the variable as follows

```
$a="'hellosir'";
```

The variable is sent by href
But when I write the variable as follows, the variable is not sent

```
$a="'hello sir'";


<ul id="myContextMenu3">
        
            <li  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="iframe.php?id=<?php echo $a; ?>" > tt</li>
            

            <li onclick="window.close()"><u>C</u>lose</li>
        </ul>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you need to url-encode your string to be working in URI, meaning that a whitespace has a special encoding. it would look like `hello+sir` AFAIK you can also ommit the single quotes, see no reason for them

in php just use

```
urlencode ( string $str )
```

or in your case

```
$a = urlencode("Hello sir");
```